# Shell script to convert trim and make it single line

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have a command

```
pdftotext -f 3 -l 3 -x 205 -y 40 -W 180 -H 75 -layout input.pdf -
```

When run it produces output as below

```
[[_थी]                    2206255388
 नाव मीराबाई sad
पतीचे नाव dame
| घर क्रमांक                Photo's |
 |वय    51 लिंग   महिला    Available |
```

I need to make each lines enclosed with double quotes and then joined to a single line separated by comma  using a shell script command?

Answer (score 1):

As an example, you could modify the output of your command like that:

```
cat <<EOF | sed 's/\(.*\)/\"\1\"/g' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/.$//'
> foobar
> bar
> foo
> EOF
"foobar","bar","foo"
```

The 1st 'sed' will add the double quotes, the 'tr' will replace the CR by a comma, last sed will remove the last comma.

So, your command will be:

```
pdftotext -f 3 -l 3 -x 205 -y 40 -W 180 -H 75 -layout input.pdf - | sed 's/\(.*\)/\"\1\"/g' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/.$//'
```